# How to segregate json data in kotlin

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I have getting response following json format. I need to message value only. how to segregate the message value. can you please help me.

```
{status:"1", message:"cu34343"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: var message: String = response?.get("message")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if response as object

```
val jsonObject = JSONTokener(response).nextValue() as JSONObject
val message = jsonObject.getString("message")// Before That check null or 
not
Log.i("message: ", message)
```

also refer different response using gson and response model class converter.